# Android GoogleMaps V2 doesnt refresh

Tags: android, google-maps, refresh, loading, invalidation

My App displays the driven route of the user. After a few seconds, the map stops loading new content and looks like this:
[image]

My Code:
XML

```
    <fragment 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    map:cameraZoom="19"
    android:layout_below="@+id/tracking_maps_colorgradient">
</fragment>
```

Java:

```
            float zoom =  18;//googleMap.getCameraPosition().zoom;
        LatLng latLng = new LatLng(lastLatitude, lastLongitude);
        locations.add(latLng);
        CameraPosition pos = new CameraPosition.Builder()
            .target(latLng)
            .bearing(bearing)
            .zoom(zoom)
            .tilt(googleMap.getCameraPosition().tilt)
            .build();

        googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(pos));
        Polyline p = googleMap.addPolyline(new PolylineOptions()
            .add(latLng)
            .width(15)
            .color(Color.RED)
            .geodesic(true));
        p.setPoints(locations);
```

Is there a way to invalidate the Map?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: No one an idea? Im still hanging on this problem...

Answer (score 0):

Ok, for this ones who have the same problem, heres the solution. The Problem is that the GoogleMap doenst refresh all the time, you have to change the camera position when the user out the boundaries.

```
LatLngBounds bounds = this.googleMap.getProjection().getVisibleRegion().latLngBounds;

if(!bounds.contains(new LatLng(gps.getLatitude(), gps.getLongitude())))        {
    //Move the camera to the user's location if they are off-screen!
    CameraPosition cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder()
  .target(new LatLng(gps.getLatitude(), gps.getLongitude()))      
  .zoom(zoom)                   // Sets the zoom
  .bearing(bearing)
  .build();                   // Creates a CameraPosition from the builder
    googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(cameraPosition));
}
```

Comment: Changing the camera position can result in a new map request to Google and end up being deducted from your quota. Be aware! Avoid repositioning with the camera where possible.

Answer (score 0):

Use Thread.sleep(300); after updating the map with markers, overlays, etc. Google Maps uses its own internal threads and need time to apply changes. It is possible that the thread adding stuff to the map is blocking Google Map's thread. The sleep will give it some time to make the update.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know there is until you have a problem. But I solved and I wanted to share with you. 
You can use handler and Thread.sleep(600). If you use just handler, you take same issue. Thread.sleep function waited for update map and than go on  your marker.